# auto-fit and minmax() don't work inside nested grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I have two nested grids - one for the layout and one for the part of my site (let's say it's a list of goods in the shop). My layout grid creates a container for the whole site, including navbar, sidebar, content, etc. And  nested grid is responsible for the list of goods only. The problem is that `auto-fit` and `minmax` functions don't work in the nested grid. You can check [this pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yoZbWo?editors=1100) to see the case.

At first, try to change width of the content, you'll see that items are changing its position according to the `auto-fit` algorithm. But as soon as you uncomment `display: grid;` for the outer grid, it responsiveness gets broken. Could you please explain why this is happening and how I can fix it?

```css
.outer-grid {
/*   display: grid; */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 700px 1fr;
}

.inner-grid {
  grid-column: 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}

.item {
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-grid">
  <div class="inner-grid">
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem is that `auto-fit` and `minmax` functions don't work in the nested grid.

I think they do work. The problem appears to be something else.

Your nested grid exists in a column with a fixed width (700px). The primary container sees no reason to shrink that column, which would trigger the `auto-fit` function in the nested grid.

Here's something you may want to consider:

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QMYMwV?editors=1100)

```css
.outer-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(1, minmax(100px, 700px)) 1fr;
}

.inner-grid {
  grid-column: 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}

.item {
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-grid">
  <div class="inner-grid">
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh, I was thinking about it, but couldn't solve it myself. Need more practice with grids.. Your solution is excellent, thanks! :)